# UIButton in UITableViewCell jumps when UITableView width is animated

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When the animation is executed to decrease the tableview width, the Trash button jumps to the left first before the animation actually starts.
The animation is executed in the ViewController.

```
UIView.Animate(0.05d, 0.15d, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, () =>
    {
        OrderProductsTableView.Frame = new CGRect(LeftPanel.Frame.Width + 130f, OrderProductsTableView.Frame.Location.Y, View.Frame.Size.Width - LeftAddProductPanel.Frame.Width, OrderProductsTableView.Frame.Size.Height);
        RightPanelFooter.Alpha = 0;
    }, null);
```

[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

The button has a constraint so that it is always 8 px in from the right side of the table view cell (which is a xib).

What I wanted/ expected was for the button to slide across in time with the animation of the tableview width changing. Am I wrongly assuming auto layout would take care of this?

I could call `reloadData()` on the tableview and re-position the button manually in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but was hoping for a slightly more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to animate the buttons as well. You can get a reference to your cells with:

```
List<UITableViewCell> cells = OrderProductsTableView.VisibleCells.ToList();
```

And then loop through the cells and modify the x position, e.g.:

```
UIView.Animate(0.05d, 0.15d, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, () =>
{
    foreach (UITableViewCell cell in cells)
    {
          MyCellType mCell = cell as MyCellType;
          mCell.trashButton.Frame = new CGRect(newXValue, newYValue, newWidthValue, newHeightValue);
    }

}, null);
```

And then also animate your Table View width as you have already done. The animations should run concurrently and your button should move with the animation for the Table View width.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 0):

it's an auto-layout issue make sure you create 2 horizontal spacing constraints one with "more or equal" >= your minimum width you want and "less than or equal" with <= your maximum space you want.

Please don't hesitate to for more information